# KVO observing of NSMangedObject in a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, core-data, key-value-observing

I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell` to display properties of a `NSMangedObject` from my model.
Each cell holds a reference to the managed object.

I also listen to changes in properties of the object by calling `addObserver:…` on the object.

The problem is that the objects can be removed from the model, and I want to unregister when this happens.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604256/how-to-do-perfect-kvo-for-nsmanagedobject), but the suggested solution there is to use `prepareForDeletion` on the object, and then manually notify the cells. This is not a very  pretty solution.

I was wondering what is the recommended solution for these cases, and more then that - is observing KVO changes on the managed object is indeed the best approach to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not use KVO for this. You need to use an `NSFetchedResultsController`, so that your tableview cells will be automatically updated using the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods.

Please see the relevant [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).